# Реализация сетки bootstap по БЭМ

Tags: bootstrap, бэм

Хочется использовать сетку bootstrap в БЭМ. Для этого переделал сетку bootstrap по методологии БЭМ. Саму методологию БЭМ использую только в css. Вроде никаких нарушений нет при внедрении сетки, но т.к. этой методологией только начал пользоваться, хочется услышать мнение профессионалов, может есть какие-либо замечания.
Сразу скажу, что библиотеку bem components использовать не желаю, т.к. мне проще верстать элементы самому. Сетку bem grid использовать не приходилось, т.к. уж очень много заморочек при ее интеграции в проект.
А вот сам код html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__row">
        <div class="container__col container__col_md_4 container__col_xs_6">Блок 1</div>
        <div class="container__col container__col_md_4 container__col_xs_6">Блок 2</div>
        <div class="container__col container__col_md_4 container__col_xs_6">Блок 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. блок container так и остался, у него есть элемент container__row, и обязательный элемент container__col, т.к. модификаторы container__col_**_* нельзя использовать самостоятельно, т.к. с точки зрения БЭМ-методологии модификатор не может использоваться в отрыве от модифицируемого блока или элемента.